# Use filestream to read a file from resources

Tags: vb.net, resources, filestream

I m trying to use filestream to get a *.exe file from my resources. my code is this: `filerdr = New FileStream(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("filename.exe"), FileMode.Open)`
but i get this error with it

> ```
> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments:
> 'Public Sub New(handle As Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle, access As System.IO.FileAccess)': Value of type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle'.
> 'Public Sub New(handle As System.IntPtr, access As System.IO.FileAccess)': Value of type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' cannot be converted to 'System.IntPtr'.
> 'Public Sub New(path As String, mode As System.IO.FileMode)': Value of type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' cannot be converted to 'String'.
> ```

I have also tried: `filerdr = New FileStream(My.Resources.filename.exe, FileMode.Open`

but still no luck, please don't give me work arounds and please tell me how to do this the way i want to do it.

I want to add `FileMode.Open` and then compare it to another file, by using

```
If filerdr.ReadByte = filerdr2.ReadByte AndAlso 
     filerdr.Length = filerdr2.Length  Then 
'''''''''''' 
End If
```

Comment: Doesn't `My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("filename.exe")` already return you a stream? You don't need a `FileStream`.

Comment: I want to add FileMode.Open . and then compare it to another file, by using
If filerdr.ReadByte = filerdr2.ReadByte AndAlso filerdr.Length = filerdr2.Length Then
''''''''''''
End If

Comment: What part of that can you not do without using a `FileStream`?

Comment: Read the comment closely...`GetStream` returns a stream - are you saying you cant read from it?

Comment: I get this error: Resource 'file' was not a Stream - call GetObject instead.
and when i use GetObject, I get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream'.

Both errors are: (InvalidOperationException was unhandled)

Comment: I tried changing filerdr from FileStream to UnManagedMemoryStream, and then i got the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. first i had to change my variable "filerdr" from FileStream to UnmanagedMemoryStream and then i had to edit the Resources.resx From this

```
<data name="MyFile" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
<value>..\Resources\MyFile.exe;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
```

To this

```
<data name="MyFile" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
<value>..\Resources\MyFile.exe;System.IO.MemoryStream, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
```

In short words. System.Byte[] to System.IO.MemoryStream.
This solved the problem and my code started working.